# Customize theme of a single View

Tags: android, android-view, android-spinner, android-theme, android-styles

I need to set `Spinner` selected item color to white in a `Spinner`, which is on a `Toolbar`. Color of all other `Spinner`s in the app should stay intact.

I tried following.

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="SpinnerOnPrimaryStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/mySpinnerItemStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="mySpinnerItemStyle" parent="android:Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_on_primary</item>
</style>
```

Toolbar

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/tab_background"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    app:theme="@style/ToolBarStyle">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/categorySpinner"
        app:theme="@style/SpinnerOnPrimaryStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

But, the color of the `Spinner` doesn't change.

If I set `android:spinnerItemStyle` of my base theme to `mySpinnerItemStyle`, the `Spinner` color gets changed. But this cahnges the color of all `Spinner`s in the app, which I don't want to happen.

(Following app theme changes spinner color, but it changes color of all spinners)

```
<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="BaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/mySpinnerItemStyle</item>
</style>
```

How can I change the color of only the `Spinner` in the `Toolbar`? It would be better if I could do this in the theme alone, without going to do it programmatically.

Comment: Instead of `app:theme` do `android:theme`.

Comment: @azizbekian tried that (also tried `style`) but no luck

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me, that as a layout to your `Spinner` items you are using one of those, that framework provides, i.e. `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item`.

If you take a look at the [source code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/simple_spinner_item.xml#L22), you'll notice, that it applies `style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"` to it's content view. This means, that when you are initializing your adapter in activity/fragment, `spinnerItemStyle` would be the one that has been applied to your activity theme, and not the one that you had explicitly applied in `xml`:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
```

You are left with two options.

### First option

Duplicate that layout content, applying the style you wish:

**my_spinner_item.xml**

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@android:id/text1"
          style="@style/MySpinnerItemStyle"
          android:singleLine="true"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:ellipsize="marquee"
          android:textAlignment="inherit"/>
```

When initializing adapter:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.my_spinner_item, list);
```

### Second option

Pass a `ContextThemeWrapper` with appropriate theme applied to the constructor of `ArrayAdapter`.

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="MySpinnerTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/MySpinnerItemStyle</item>
</style>
```

When initializing adapter:

```
Context wrappedContext = new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.MySpinnerTheme);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(wrappedContext, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
```

Comment: Very well explained here sir!